# Copy UITextField string to UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

How Can I copy `UITextField` string to `UITextView`? 
I want to do it when `UIButton`;

```
[myUIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UITextField* textField (initialized, omit code here)
[self.view addSubview:textField];
//save string to the property
self.textFieldString = textField.text; 
//textFieldString is @property NSString* textFieldString; at the header.

UITextView* textView (initialized, omit code here)
[self.textView setEditable:false]; 
[self.view addSubview:self.textView];

//here i want to implement UITextField string -> UITextView display
-(void)submitButtonClicked {
 //....
 //Problem i am having here is that, I can not see instance variable other than @property variable.  How should I pass UITextField  .text to UITextView?
}
```

Comment: so make textView an ivar and you'll see it

Comment: You can also tag the text field and text view and retrieve them. Ex: `[self.view viewWithTag:kTxtFieldTag]`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prepare the identifier to each UI**

```
[textField setTag:100];

[self.view addSubview:textField];


[textView setTag:200];

[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

**Identify the each UI element and Manage**

```
-(void)submitButtonClicked {

    //Problem i am having here is that,
    // I can not see instance variable other than @property variable.
    // How should I pass UITextField  .text to UITextView?

    UITextField *myTextField=(UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
    UITextView *myTextView=(UITextView*)[self.view viewWithTag:200];

    myTextView.text=myTextField.text;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It worked.  Have another question here.  It will create UITextField and UITextView every time method get called.  Don't you get a memory trouble?

This way seems better,
  // property UITextField *myTextField;
  // property UITextView *myTextView;
then use them in the method with self.myTextField = self.myTextView
Which means, it will just use local property variable without creating new classes.

Comment: Yes You are right, you should keep them as instance variable, but you had asked "How should I pass UITextField  .text to UITextView?". To make this happen i did like this. You were right & modify the code as u needed. all the best!

Comment: i got it.  All the best.

Answer (score 0):

In your button's action use:

```
textView.text=textField.text;
```

Declare your variables between @interface and @end and initialize them in the viewDidLoad. This way you'll be able to use them in your button's action.

```
@interface ViewController ()

{
    UITextView *textView;
    UITextField *textField;

}

@implementation ViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
// Do the following
// Initialize both textView and textField
// Set their frames
// Add both of them as a subview to your view
}

@end
```

Now you'll be able to access both of them in your button's action.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating UITextView programatically then create a property variable and synthesize the same. You can access the same using the synthesized name and in UIButton action method get the text and set it to UITextView.

In .m file you can declare UITextView as

```
@interface classname () {
    UITextView *textView
}
```

or in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *textView;
```

As you have described the problem 'Problem i am having here is that, I can not see instance variable other than @property variable.  How should I pass UITextField  .text to UITextView?'